# My php page doesn't receive variables, even with session, where am I wrong?

Tags: php, session, post, session-variables

Yes i know, this question is popular here but I tried various solutions proposed in the previous similar topis and nothing seems to work.

Maybe the structure of my work isn't the best way to code but I'm learning.
The code starts with a form.php (only a little snippet of php, the remaining code in html), it passes credentials to the db config file that checks username e pw,then I would get the access to a certain php page.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['log'])) $_SESSION['log']=false;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<a bunch of html/css ecc>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <label><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required>

      <label ><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"required>

      <button type="submit" formaction="configDB.php">Login as admin </button>
      <button type="submit" formaction="configDB-guest.php">Login as guest </button>

    </div>

  </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The configDB is something like this:

```
<?php
//session_start();
//if(!isset($_SESSION['log'])) $_SESSION['log']=false;

$host='localhost';
$user=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$dbname="admin";

mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$verif=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guest WHERE username='$user' AND password='$password'") OR 
                    die("Unable to connect".mysql_error());

$verif_login=mysql_fetch_array($verif);
//pick data from db
if(($verif_login['username']==$user) AND ($verif_login['password']==$password)AND ($verif_login['role']=='admin')) 
{
    echo("<p align='center'>Welcome $user</p>" );
    //$_SESSION['username']=$user;
    //$_SESSION['password']=$password;
    //$_SESSION['log']=true;
    $logged=1;
    header('Location: home.php?var1="$logged"'); 
    exit();
```

In which are visible my attempts to set $_SESSION and the variable embedded in the header link.
Then the page that I want to reach is home.php:

```
<?php

$admin_=$_GET['logged']; //doesn't works

if(!isset($_SESSION['log'])) $_SESSION['log']=false; 

if($_SESSION['log']!=true)
{

    header('URL=form_login.php');//this is the only thing that works

}
```

....and html again.
It seems that home.php doesn't receive nothing from connectDB, I think thare is something that I miss.

Comment: (1) You should **not be storing passwords in your database as plain text**. (2) `mysql_` functions have been deprecated long time ago, and are removed in PHP7. Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Where is the starting form tag

Comment: In normal PHP applications, requests are independent from each other, therefore you need to call `session_start()` in each page that wants to use the session, see the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php Yes, that function should have been named `session_start_or_resume()`.

Comment: @Terry I know, but this isn't a real application. +lostmylogin i cut it off accidentally, anyway the code works fine but I cannot deny the access to home.php

Comment: It doesn't matter: that is insecure and bad coding habit. Works fine !== secure.

Comment: Header statement should be `header('Location: post.php?var1='.$logged);`, and subsequently change `$admin_=$_GET['logged'];` to `$admin_=$_GET['var1'];`

Comment: @Terry the application will be run in local, I know the security is important, but will you lock your bike even if you were in a deserted island?

Comment: But if that means you will convince yourself not to lock your bike back in civilisation, then yes, it's a stupid idea whatsoever. But hey, it's your code. I'm not here to mother you, but to give sound advice.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul thanks a lot, it works!! But the fact that $_SESSION isn't passed remains a mistery

Comment: @J.Dillinger I don't see any `session_start();` statement in *home.php* page. Have you started session anywhere in *that* page?

Comment: Previously I tried to put session_start(); in home but nothing changes.